How can I update the output registers manually of an RP2400 (Raspberry Pi Pico) in C?
I am currently tinkering with a Raspberry Pi Pico and I want to write my own functions to setup the outputs and writing to it by manipulating the registers. I am currently only changing registers within the SIO, namely for setting up the GPIO direction: GPIO_OE_SET, GPIO_OE_CLR and for writing to the Ouput: GPIO_OUT_SET, GPIO_OUT_CLR. This is my current code, have I missed something? Thank you in Advance!
#define SIO_BASE_P 0xd0000000
#define GPIO_IN_OFFSET 0x004
#define GPIO_OUT_OFFSET 0x010
#define GPIO_OUT_SET_OFFSET 0x014
#define GPIO_OUT_CLR_OFFSET 0x018
#define GPIO_OUT_XOR_OFFSET 0x01c
#define GPIO_OE_OFFSET 0x020
#define GPIO_OE_SET_OFFSET 0x024
#define GPIO_OE_CLR_OFFSET 0x028

void custom_set_gpio_dir(uint gpio, bool dir)
{
  uint32_t* gpio_oe_set_p = (uint32_t*)(SIO_BASE_P + GPIO_OE_SET_OFFSET);
  uint32_t* gpio_oe_clr_p = (uint32_t*)(SIO_BASE_P + GPIO_OE_CLR_OFFSET);
  if(dir)
   {
     (*gpio_oe_set_p) |= (1 << gpio);
   }
  else
  {
     (*gpio_oe_clr_p) |= (1 << gpio);
  }
}

void custom_set_gpio_output(uint gpio, bool out)
{
  uint32_t* gpio_out_set_p = (uint32_t*)(SIO_BASE_P + GPIO_OUT_SET_OFFSET);
  uint32_t* gpio_out_clr_p = (uint32_t*)(SIO_BASE_P + GPIO_OUT_CLR_OFFSET);
  if(out)
   {
     (*gpio_out_set_p) |= (1 << gpio);
   }
  else
   {
     (*gpio_out_clr_p) |= (1 << gpio);
   }
}

The program compiles successfully, but the output is not set as I would expect it to.
int main() 
{
  custom_set_gpio_dir(25, true);
  custom_set_gpio_output(25, true);
  while(true)
  {}
  return 0;
}


The registers should probably be accessed through pointer-to-volatile (i.e. volatile uint32_t* reg).

but the output is not set as I would expect it to. - this does not tell us much. It could be that your expectation is wrong.

Check out How to access a hardware register from firmware?

You should probably use the Pico C SDK.

Or at least use the SDK for low-level register access. This will make it easy to use the Pico's address aliasing feature for atomic bit SET/CLEAR/XOR operations.

i think you are using the SET and CLR registers incorrectly. Since these are write-only registers with "write 1 to set" and "write 1 to clear" semantics, you should use = rather than |=.

This code works (on the original Pico):
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void DELAY ( unsigned int );

#define RESETS_BASE                 0x4000C000

#define RESETS_RESET_RW             (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x0000)
#define RESETS_RESET_XOR            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x1000)
#define RESETS_RESET_SET            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x2000)
#define RESETS_RESET_CLR            (RESETS_BASE+0x0+0x3000)

#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_RW        (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x0000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_XOR       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x1000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_SET       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x2000)
#define RESETS_RESET_DONE_CLR       (RESETS_BASE+0x8+0x3000)

#define SIO_BASE                    0xD0000000

#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_RW             (SIO_BASE+0x10)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_SET            (SIO_BASE+0x14)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR            (SIO_BASE+0x18)
#define SIO_GPIO_OUT_XOR            (SIO_BASE+0x1C)

#define SIO_GPIO_OE_RW              (SIO_BASE+0x20)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_SET             (SIO_BASE+0x24)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_CLR             (SIO_BASE+0x28)
#define SIO_GPIO_OE_XOR             (SIO_BASE+0x2C)

#define IO_BANK0_BASE               0x40014000

#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_STATUS_RW   (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0C8+0x0000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_STATUS_XOR  (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0C8+0x1000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_STATUS_SET  (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0C8+0x2000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_STATUS_CLR  (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0C8+0x3000)

#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_RW     (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x0000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_XOR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x1000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_SET    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x2000)
#define IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_CLR    (IO_BANK0_BASE+0x0CC+0x3000)

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    PUT32(RESETS_RESET_CLR,1<<5); //IO_BANK0
    while(1)
    {
        if((GET32(RESETS_RESET_DONE_RW)&(1<<5))!=0) break;
    }
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OE_CLR,1<<25);
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_CLR,1<<25);
    PUT32(IO_BANK0_GPIO25_CTRL_RW,5); //SIO
    PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OE_SET,1<<25);
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++)
    {
        PUT32(SIO_GPIO_OUT_XOR,1<<25);
        DELAY(0x10000);
    }
    return(0);
}

Some assembly, I avoid volatile pointers in general.  You need to use volatile if you want to take that pointer approach.
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl DELAY
.thumb_func
DELAY:
    sub r0,#1
    bne DELAY
    bx lr

The IO bank starts off in reset, you need release reset to the IO so you can mess with it.  Are you missing this?
Why did I make it an input and output a zero first?  I saw them do it that way in their code (which if I remember was quite bloated and took a while to wade through).  Do you have to do that?  Probably not.
The gpio FUNCSEL resets to 0x1f which is NULL you have to select SIO for the gpio pin to use sio to manipulate it.  Are you missing that step?
Then as someone pointed out in the comments, you are doing read write things
(*gpio_out_clr_p) |= (1 << gpio);

using a write only clear register.  You write 1 to the CLR register to clear that bit.  Or set to set or XOR to toggle.  So you can or equal the read write register or you can write the set register.  I don't know what happens if you read a write only register, the or equals might clear or set more things that you wanted.  Since they have clear and set registers then just use them with a write.
The schematic does show GPIO25 and the other end is tied to ground so that implies that SETting gpio 25 will turn the led on.
You are quite close, and you did a lot of good work to get this far, but... just a couple more steps.
